# When logged into azure devops services how long does your session last for before logging you out?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps Services, if we wanted to grant a user a temporary permission, like Project Collection Administrator, and then removed the user from that permission the user still has that permission for the duration of their session.
Closing the tab or browser does not log them out, only logging out and logging back in updates the permission.
So my questions are:
How long does a session last?
Is a session timeout configurable?
Or is there another way of providing just in time access to Azure DevOps Services?

Granted a user the permission of Project Collection Administrator then got the user to login.
Remove the user from that permission.
The user still had that permission after being revoked permission.
Only until the user logged out and back in was the user reverted to previous perms.

Expect: user to no longer have access. Or shorten the session duration.

Answer (score 0):

In my test, once I remove a user from the Project Collection Administrators group, the user will **immediately** lose the PCA permission. The current user may also be able to see the page that PCA can see. Once the user refreshes the page or attempts to perform an operation that PCA has permission to do, he will notice that he cannot view the previous page or is prompted that he does not have permission.

For example, if I add a user only to the PCA group, this user can access all projects. After removing this user from PCA group:

- If the user refreshes the browser, he can't see any project.
  [image]
- If the current user does not refresh the browser, he can still see all projects. Once he clicks on any of the projects, he will encounter a 401 error.
  [image]

Project Collection Administrators can manage all the resources and permissions of the entire organization. Please be careful about granting user PCA permissions.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry I should have included that we are trying to use [Privileged Identity Management groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/id-governance/privileged-identity-management/groups-activate-roles) to control the duration in which a user has that elevated permission. So an Entra ID group is granted PCA and the user has an eligible assignment to the group, which needs to be activated by the user, for a specified duration then the membership is automatically removed

Comment: Is there a better way to automate temporary access to an elevated permission for admins or does DevOps only process Entra ID group membership on login and manual admin intervention is needed to provide that temporary access?

Comment: If you are using PIM group in Azure, as you have noticed in the official doc, users have elevated access in Azure DevOps for **up to 1 hour** after their PIM group access gets deactivated. Synchronizing from Azure Entra ID to Azure DevOps takes time. If you want these users to lose PCA permissions faster, as a workaround, you can deactivate the group in Azure Entra ID and remove the group from the Azure DevOps PCA group at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

So I have now found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/security-best-practices?view=azure-devops#just-in-time-access-for-admin-groups) that mentions the group should be a role-assignable security group in Entra ID. [Role-assignable group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNGIQ.png)
My previous method used a security group that was not role-assignable.
I'll give that a go and report back.

Comment: So once the group was activated I logged in and had PCA permissions. I manually deactivated the group and I still had PCA permissions (refreshed the page and able to access other projects).
The duration of membership of the group was set at 1.5 hours so I'll wait until that has past before trying to access other projects again.

Comment: Think I have found my answer - just read the note on the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/security-best-practices?view=azure-devops#just-in-time-access-for-admin-groups) that says:
'*Users have elevated access in Azure DevOps for up to 1 hour after their PIM group access gets deactivated.*' so permissions containg Entra ID groups must be refreshed periodically and are not instant.

Answer (score 0):

So ended up logging a support call as from our testing it looks as though if users are cloud only users then the permissions are re-evaluated up to an hour after the PIM group permission is deactivated. If users are sync'd from on-premises then permissions don't seem to be re-evaluated in the same way.